# Админка на бустраповском темплейте

Tags: bootstrap, шаблоны

Всем привет,
Устанавливаю на админку темплейт http://github.meritoo.pl/Bootstrap-3-Admin-Theme/tables.html
Есть несколько вопросов :

надо зайти на http://dev9.softreactor.com/ci22/admin/admin/login  под логином ciAdmin 111111
далее заходим на страницу  http://dev9.softreactor.com/ci22/admin/hostel/index и вверху в списке Operator выбираем 2->Operator_1 - у него много данных
В частности проблемы :

1. Данные в некоторых ячейках длинные и поэтому ячейки разносятся на несколько строк - что мне не нравится.
   Первоначально там было колонок больше - я часть попрятал - но там была таблица на полную ширину.
   Как с этим лучше бороться ? - при том что хочется чтобы в списке было как много больше инфы.
   Можно спрятав еще несколько колонок отображать недостающую инфу вос всплывающем окне по ссылочке. Я когда-то пользовал overlib для этого.
   У boostrap-а есть что-то удобнее overlib-а?
   Или еще какие-либо варианты решения этой проблемы?
2. Дело в том что в  исходном темплейте есть не все нужные мне блоки  и приходится выдумывать самому.
   Вот на упомянутой странице мне нужно было сделать блок с фильтром - я нарисовал как мог - но выглядит не очень...
   Посоветуйте,  плиз ка клучше организовать блок с фильтром .
3. если сравнить страницу выше со страницей http://dev9.softreactor.com/ci22/admin/operator/index/page/1
   то на последней не отображаются фоном строки с классом even. Я так и не понял почему - по верстке строки вроде разные.
4. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в меню слева элементы начинающиеся с "!" там есть списки и некоторые редакторы - что вам бросится в глаза как неправильное.
   Я пхп-разработчик. HTML есно знаю неплохо, но сделать сложную и КРАСИВУЮ вертску для меня сложно - хочется попрактиковаться с установкой бутсраповских
   темплейтов.

Спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

> 3) если сравнить страницу выше со страницей http://dev9.softreactor.com/ci22/admin/operator/index/page/1 то на последней не отображаются фоном строки с классом `even`. Я так и не понял почему - по верстке строки вроде разные.

строки с классом `even` не красятся потому что вы все содержимое таблицы запихнули в `thead`. Перенесите в `tbody` и будет все хорошо.